# SELECT statement as a parameter in IF

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use result from one query and proceed depending on the result

I am using Oracle

```
if 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ABC is null
then 
Print 'NO result';
else 
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ABC
```

Expected output

```
If table is NULL : No Result

if table is not Null the the content of table
```

Comment: Your first SQL is incorrect: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_ABC is null` Looks like you are missing the word `WHERE`.

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, so is the code you posted actually PL/SQL?

Comment: Under what circumstances this logic is gonna be used? Is it a script you will execute regularly via, say, SQL*PLUS, or is it a one-time ad-hoc query or this is gonna be put in a stored procedure/function and called by a client application?

Answer (score 2):

You will need PL/SQL block to achieve this:

```
declare
  cnt number:= 0;
  RC SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  select count(1) into cnt from table_abc where rownum = 1;
  if cnt = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('no result');
  else
    OPEN RC FOR select * from table_abc;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(RC);
  end if;
end;
/
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```sql
SELECT 'Found' AS Myinfo, Field1, Field2, Field3

FROM

TABLE_ABC

UNION ALL


SELECT
'No Result' As MyInfo, NULL AS Field1, NULL AS Field2, NULL AS Field3
WHERE NOT EXISTS


(  SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_ABC )
```

Comment: Are you sure that your syntax is correct as I am not able to see `FROM` clause in second query before `WHERE` clause

Comment: This is something you can do in SQL Server-  its possible you can do this in Oracle as well, I don't know for sure. However, if you can't, you just need a single dummy row, for example you can use the COUNT .... 

SELECT  'No Result' As MyInfo, NULL AS Field1, NULL AS Field2, NULL AS Field3 FROM (select count(*) ct1 FROM Anytable ) AS t1  WHERE NOT EXISTS

( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_ABC )


or maybe even try ...


SELECT  'No Result' As MyInfo, COUNT(*) FROM Anytable ...

You might be able to play with that.

Comment: Acceptable!! In oracle, It is not possible. It should be something like you have written in comment and not in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```sql
SELECT
    'Found' AS Myinfo,
    Field1,
    Field2,
    Field3
FROM
    TABLE_ABC

UNION ALL

SELECT

      'No Result' As MyInfo,

      NULL AS Field1,

      NULL AS Field2, 

      NULL AS Field3 

FROM

      (  SELECT COUNT(*) ct1 FROM Anytable ) AS DummySingleRow

WHERE NOT EXISTS

      ( SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_ABC )
```